# Google AppEngine Latency problems since Friday (com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

A number of us have been having massive problems with our sites where the latency is averaging about 20 seconds for responses and the warmups and server startups seem to be all over the place.... can someone from google please help us out, according to your own status screen (http://code.google.com/status/appengine) everything appears normal, but its definitely NOT normal for us

```
/diarybooker/admin
119  1393    21590 ms
/diarybooker/appointment
21   1232    40398 ms
/diarybooker/contact
15   7168    10424 ms
/_ah/warmup
12   2212    40981 ms
```

There is more of a discusson on this at:

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/vRqnH34D_1I
```

Other apps that I know are having trouble are:

```
http://vectortracking.appspot.com 
http://mybikeshopmanager.appspot.com/
http://commanderepas.appspot.com
```